# Can federal courts overturn state court decisions on matters of state law?

Tags: united-states, federal-courts, federalism, us-states, state-courts

If a state court rules, for example, that a particular state law is unconstitutional under the state constitution, can this decision be overturned by a federal court?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No.**

Federal courts, when sitting in diversity jurisdiction,* are obligated to follow state law as articulated by state courts, as the Supreme Court ruled in [*Erie Railroad Company v. Tompkins*](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1900-1940/304us64). If there is no controlling state court precedent, the federal court may "guess" how the state supreme court would have ruled, but for particularly important issues of law, it is preferable for the federal court to certify the question to the state supreme court instead.

Under no circumstances may a federal court second-guess a state supreme court's determinations of state law. A federal court may find that a state law conflicts with a federal statute or with the (federal) Constitution, but it may not say, for example, "the state supreme court got the (state) law wrong."

* It is unlikely that a state law would be relevant under any other theory of federal jurisdiction, but [28 USC 1652](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/1652) does not explicitly limit the doctrine to diversity jurisdiction, so in the implausible scenario where a court *not* sitting in diversity jurisdiction nevertheless has to apply state law, it must still follow the state law.

Comment: There are a few major areas outside of diversity cases where the federal judiciary must use state law. Copyright cases in particular are exclusively federal, but many  such cases involve a licenses that are tied into contracts, and contracts are governed by state law.  Side claims in in a controvery with specifically federal character can also pull in state law (although many such cases will also be diversity cases). Diversity cases probably are the most common reason though.

Comment: Would it be possible for someone to argue in federal court that a state court's judicial conduct in a case violated e.g. 14th Amendment protections--that the law as written by the legislature was compatible with the Fourteenth Amendment, but that judges were e.g. capriciously ignoring the statute to the detriment of one of the parties on account of race?

Comment: Doesn't this assume supreme court precedents cannot be thrown out?  The US court system is currently "whatever SCOTUS decides" (Dobbs v. Jackson Women's Health Organization) (Citizens United) (Janus v. Council Number 31), (Ramos v. Louisiana), how it ruled in previous cases is no longer binding in practice.  To determine what SCOTUS will decide, we need to look at what the federalist society wants, not previous court case decisions, which will in turn depend on who benefits from the ruling.

Comment: @Yakk: The *Erie* doctrine dates to the 1930s and is an extremely well-established principle of federalism. It is unlikely that the Federalist Society would want to overturn it, as doing so would infringe on state sovereignty.

Comment: @supercat: Case law is considered a kind of law (under the American common law system). A state court decision that violates the (federal) Constitution is treated no differently to a state statute that violates the Constitution.

Comment: @Kevin Sure, but my point is that what matters is the political position of the Federalist Society on the issue, not prior precedent, as the Federalist Society has taken control over the US Supreme Court.  An answer **No** justified by the color of raspberries should be corrected: so should reasoning on what the law says based on precedent in this era.  Precedent is as irrelevant as fruit color.

Comment: @Yakk: This is Law.SE, not Politics.SE. I'm giving an answer based on the applicable case law, not based on political considerations. If you want to discuss the politics of this issue, please ask a question there instead of here.

Comment: @kevin Thr docterine of precident is a custom: it no longer holds in the US court system.  No statute demands precident hold, only the custom of the courts.  And if the custom.has changed, citing it is nonsensr.  The specific political positions that decide the law, or why this has happened, is off topic: but shouldn't the actual fact that precident is not binding mean that any argument based on precident being absolute is currently incorrect?  I am not talking about the politics, just the facts on the ground.  In france precident does not bind; neither now in usa.

Comment: @Yakk: Precedent is binding on the lower courts, and it has never been (entirely) binding on the Supreme Court. *Erie* itself overturned *Swift v. Tyson.* Unless and until the Supreme Court overturns *Erie*, it remains good law. That is simply how the American system works. Speculation about what the Supreme Court might or might not do in the future is not law, it is politics.

Answer (score 1):

Any cause of action advanced at the federal level must have a federal basis, such  federal law, the federal constitution, or general legal principles accepted by the federal courts. Simply asserting that a lower court interpreted the state constitution incorrectly is not a federal cause of action. But a state court decision can be challenged in federal court if a federal basis for the challenge can be given. For instance, in Bush v. Gore, Bush argued that the Florida Supreme Court's order of a recount violated the Equal Protection clause of the federal constitution, and so stayed the order.

Also, you ask about a decision "that a particular state law is unconstitutional under the state constitution". This would be especially hard to argue in federal court, as it's likely that the only party with standing would be the state government, and it would rather weird for the state executive branch to ask the federal judicial branch to overrule the state judicial branch. Federal courts are for resolving disputes between individuals and the government, or between governments of different states, not disputes between different branches of the same state government.

A decision that a particular state law *is* constitutional is more likely to result in a federal basis for appeal, since anyone charged with a crime under the law would have standing. While they wouldn't be able to challenge the finding that the state constitution fails to bar the law in question, there are various other assertions that they *would* be able to assert. For instance, they could assert that the law violates the federal constitution. If they had originally argued that the state didn't have jurisdiction, and the state Supreme Court found that the state constitution does give jurisdiction, they could argue in federal court against the finding of jurisdiction. Etc.